# How to use Jupyter Lab with ipv6 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Could someone help me to use Jupyter Lab with ipv6 on Ubuntu?
I have google everywhere but I could not find the answer.

I've tried both 
`jupyter lab --ip=::1` or `jupyter lab --ip=MY_IPV6` it's not working.

When I connect to [::1]:8888 and [MY_IPV6]:8888 Google Chrome says "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

I can ping [::1] and I can ping MY_IPV6

I can ensure that jupyter lab work fine with ipv4 with 127.0.0.1:8888 or using port forwarding, everything is fine.

Maybe, can Jupyter Lab not support ipv6?

Updated: ipv6 for Jupyter Lab do work on Windows, but It doesn't work on Ubuntu. 
Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### update!

There is no longer any downside, I just found out that you can just use `::` for the ip.

EASY!

## Solved!

Finally, I found the way. Since the command `jupyter lab --ip=MY_IPV6` isn't working, so, I guess changing the config will do nothing but actually what you need to do is to **change jupyter config**, and here are the steps.

#### 1. Generate your config

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Writing default config to: /home/zen3515/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

#### 2. Edit the config

```
$ gedit /home/zen3515/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Add the below lines to the config

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '::'
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = True
```

Explaination

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = 'xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx'    <--- listen to your ipv6
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'                                <--- connect from different host 
c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = True                         <--- CORS's thing
```

#### 3. Start JupyterLab

```
$ jupyter lab --no-browser
```

#### 4. Connect from anywhere using your ipv6 in this format

```
[xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]:8888
```

The only downside to this method is that you must connect using you ipv6 only.
You cannot use '0.0.0.0' or 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' or '::1', but if you want to, I guess you can [edit the hosts file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691293/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file).

Answer (score 2):

Not on Ubuntu, but on Windows I was able to just follow [the instructions for running a notebook server](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html) and then use `jupyter-notebook --ip='*' --no-browser` to access with IPv6 address.